# HTML Input remove last char letter spacing

Tags: html, css, input

I have a HTML input with `maxlength=4` attribute on it and it works well.
The thing is when I type the last character - it hides the first one while i'm focused on the input. when I lose focus (blur) the inputs looks ok.

Here's a visual explanation:

While typing:

[image]

When I get to `4` it looks like this (1 is hidden):

[image]

When I lose focus:

[image]

Here is my HTML input:

`<input name="input[input-1]" type="text" maxlength="4" style="letter-spacing:15px;" class="numeric">`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please post your html code and the css. Unless this two codes it is impossible to answer

Comment: Ok, i've updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

provide your html css code here. if you are using **type="number"** and a fixed width it might be for the reserved place in type number for the **increment** and **decrement** arrows.

i can't see any problem here :

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="9999" value="1">
```